# Angular 2 route check if params contains valid value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I've got the following code in one angular2 component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.elementsService.getElement(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(element => {
                    this.elementToEdit = element;
                }
      );
  }
```

This component is being used in two cases, one where an `id` is provided in the url and one where there is no `id` provided. In the first case, it works fine. In the second, it works BUT there is a 404 error in the console: `api/elements/NaN`.

I am trying to fix that, but I couldn't find a way check if the `id` is in the url or not:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.route.params['id']){<---doesn't work
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.elementsService.getElement(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(element => {
                    this.elementToEdit = element;
                }
      );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this and avoid calling the service if the `id` parameter is not present?

Comment: Why you are using same route you can create two one with id one without id ?

Comment: did you try logging value of `+params['id']` when id is provided?

Comment: @BabarBilal I am trying to reuse the same code for create new elements and edit existing ones, so if there is no id in the param I create a new element, and if there is an id, then I edit the existing one.

Comment: updated the answer you can simply do both actions in if/else is there any problem in this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using this in one of my project working fine for me

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
 if (params.id) {
  // Edit your element here
 } else {
  // Create your new element here
 }
});
```

and my route is this

```
{ path: "home/:id", component: HomeComponent },
```

Comment: you saved me from a minor headache